# Feature selection problem under promise

Tags: machine-learning, it.information-theory, subset-sum, lattice, integer-lattice

Are there well used examples of feature selection problem where the problem is defined under certain promise? Let's say the task is to select the minimum number of features such that the mutual information of the selected features is under a certain threshold or the mutual information of a certain other type of clustering is over the threshold.